# Unable to Deploy Spree to Apache with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, spree

I have an Ubuntu 10.04 server running Apache with phusion passenger that I've been using to host rails apps. I'm unable to get spree to deploy to the server properly. The bundle installs properly, and I can run the application from `rails s mongrel` just fine. But when I visit the site from apache/passenger I receive this error.

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started

Error message:
 /home/webdeploy/websitename/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end ...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_websitename_session' ^
Exception class:
 SyntaxError
Application root:
 /home/webdeploy/websitename
```

Could this be related to the version of ruby installed? It is 1.8.7 by the looks of the backtrace.

**Backtrace**

```
#   File    Line    Location
0   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  234 in `load'
1   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  234 in `load'
2   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  225 in `load_dependency'
3   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb  234 in `load'
4   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb  556 
5   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb  555 in `each'
6   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/engine.rb  555 
7   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb   30  in `instance_exec'
8   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb   30  in `run'
9   /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb   55  in `run_initializers'
10  /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb   54  in `each'
11  /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/initializable.rb   54  in `run_initializers'
12  /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/application.rb 96  in `initialize!'
13  /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb    30  in `send'
14  /home/webdeploy/websitename/spree/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb    30  in `method_missing'
15  /home/webdeploy/websitename/config/environment.rb   5   
16  /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 36  in `gem_original_require'
17  /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb 36  in `require'
18  config.ru   3   
19  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb   46  in `instance_eval'
20  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rack/builder.rb   46  in `initialize'
21  config.ru   1   in `new'
22  config.ru   1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to using ruby 1.8.7 on the server. I upgraded to current ruby from ruby-lang.org and everything worked out.